# Что нужно изменить в коде?

Tags: c, сортировка

Мне нужно проделать сортировку массива двумя методами,я проделал ее по возрастанию,как изменить ее на сортировку по убыванию?

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    int n = 1,n2 = 1,N = 9;
    int a[N],arr[N];
    int buff = 0;   // для хранения перемещаемого значения
    int i, j,b;     // для цикла        
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Программа заполняющая массив случайными девятью числами в диапазоне от 60 до 80");
    printf("\nСортировка полученного массива методом Вставок");
    printf("\nЗаполнение второго массива из девяти чисел числами из диапазона от 60 до 80");
    printf("\nСортировка его методом Вставок и методом Пузырька\n\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i] = 60 + rand() % 21;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = a[i];
    }
    puts("Массив имеет вид:");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\nСортировка его методом Вставок:\n");
    /************* Начало сортировки *******************/
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        buff = a[i]; // запомним обрабатываемый элемент
        // и начнем перемещение элементов слева от него
        // пока заполненный не окажется меньше чем перемещаемый
        for (j = i - 1; j <= 0 && a[j] < buff; j--)
            a[j + 1] = a[j];    
        a[j + 1] = buff; // и поставим заполненный на его новое место   
        printf("\nЭтап сортировки:");
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%3d", a[j]);
        n++;
        putchar('\n');
        putchar('\n');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    /************* Конец сортировки *******************/
    putchar('\n');
    printf("\nОтсортированый массив методом вставки имеет вид: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) // вывод  отсортированного массива
        printf("%3d", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    putchar('\n');
    /************* Вторая сортировка *******************/
    printf("\n\n\nСортировка Методом Пузырька\n");
    printf("\n\nИсходный массив имеет вид:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d", arr[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++ )//сортировка пузырьком
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                b = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];

                arr[j+1] = b;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\nЭтап сортировки :");
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%3d", arr[j]);
        n2++;   
        putchar('\n');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
    printf("\nОтсортированый массив методом пузырька имеет вид: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%3d", arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: У Вас код на С, зачем Вам метка с++?

Answer (score 0):

Пузырек - вообще элементарно: заменить знак `>` на `<`:

```
    for(j = 0; j < N-i-1; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] < arr[j+1])
        {
            b = arr[j];
```

А метод вставками надо переписывать - он у вас не работает...

Правильно написанная сортировка меняется на обратную просто путем изменения вида сравнения на обратное.

Comment: А как исправить метод вставок?

Comment: А его надо переписывать - он у вас не сортирует... Вот, сами убедитесь: https://ideone.com/3TwIiu

Comment: Сортировку по возрастанию он проводит,значит его надо полностью переписать под убывание?

Comment: Он неверно сортирует! По ссылке - `Отсортированый массив методом вставки имеет вид: 
 79 65 77 76 64 61 80 80 77` - это ваша программа без единого изменения. Согласитесь, это трудно считать отсортированным массивом...

Comment: Да тут лучше все переписать....

Comment: Хм странно,у меня все сортирует по возрастанию корректно:Отсортированный массив методом вставки имеет вид:
 27 28 31 39 46 47 47 50 57

Comment: Посмотрите, что не так по ссылке https://ideone.com/3TwIiu - простите, но это ваш код...  Все, что я добавил - `#include<stdlib.h>`, чтоб компилировался код...